# jpa, trying to create table from entities, class not found ExpressionVisitor

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm having some troubles creating tables from entities in eclipse.
This project was originally on eclipse on windows where I created entities from mysql tables and imported it to the project. Everything was working great. Yesterday I decided to switch from windows to ubuntu and thus I just made a back up of the eclipse project thinking I could create tables from the entities anyway.

So when I right click on the project -> JPA tools -> create tables from entities,

I get the following error :

> Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack:
>       Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20140809-296a69f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
>       Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicClassLoader@6eceb130
>       Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20140809-296a69f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>       Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [my-pu] failed.
>       Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/ExpressionVisitor
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException.exceptionSearchingForPersistenceResources(PersistenceUnitLoadingException.java:127)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:107)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:179)
>       at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.buildEntityManagerFactory(Main.java:94)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.core.ddlgen.Main.main(Main.java:68)
>       Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20140809-296a69f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>       Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [my-pu] failed.
>       Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/ExpressionVisitor
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.createPredeployFailedPersistenceException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1973)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1964)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.callPredeploy(JPAInitializer.java:98)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:96)
>       ... 5 more
>       Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20140809-296a69f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>       Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [my-pu] failed.
>       Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/ExpressionVisitor
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:231)
>       ... 9 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/parser/ExpressionVisitor
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata.addJPAQuery(NamedQueryMetadata.java:105)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata.process(NamedQueryMetadata.java:192)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processQueries(MetadataProject.java:1630)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.addNamedQueries(MetadataProcessor.java:148)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1915)
>       ... 7 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.parser.ExpressionVisitor
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 12 more

Wildfly by default uses hibernate as JPA provider, I did switch it to EclipseLink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the target library to be the user defined library in properties-> jpa.

Then I followed this tut : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjCCQSJVtVQ

basically :

```
<persistence-unit name="my-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <jta-data-source>java:/forumcsDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/forumcs"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="X"/>
        <property name="eclipseLink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipseLink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"/>

    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

and then I switched back to the old persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to add provider to persistence-unit in your persistence.xml 
and ensure eclipse link jar are in Wildfly classpath

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

See More https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UpdateyourPersistence.xmlforHibernate4.3.0

Comment: I've the persistence provider already :  <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>